# how to prove that an entire function is positive on the real axis

Tags: functions, riemann-zeta

The error function $\mathrm{erf}(x)$ is defined as:
$$\mathrm{erf}(x):=\frac {2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^{2}}dt\tag{1}$$

Let us define the following 3 functions:

$$h(y)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathrm{erf}(1+i y)+\mathrm{erf}(1-i y)\right)\tag{2}$$

$$f(y)=e\sqrt{\pi}(2y^2+1)e^{-y^2}h(y)+2\left(\cos(2y) - y\sin(2y)\right) \tag{3}$$

$$g(y)=e\sqrt{\pi}y(2y^2-1)e^{-y^2}h(y)+2\left(y\cos(2y)+(y^2-1)\sin(2y)\right) \tag{4}$$

We also have:
$$\frac{df}{dy}(y)=-2 g(y)$$

Here is a plot of $\color{red}{\log(f^2(y))}$ and $\color{blue}{\log(g^2(y))}$ vs. $y$:
[image]

Question:
How to prove that the following sum-of-square function $\phi(y)$ is always positive:

$$\phi(y):=f^2(y)+g^2(y)>0,\qquad y\in \mathbb{R}\tag{5}$$

This problem showed up when I was looking for some approximation to Riemann $\Xi(z)$ function.

I will soon describe several unsuccessful attempts that I tried.

Best regards-
mike

Comment: $h,f,g$ are real functions, so what is the issue in proving that $f^2(y)+g^2(y)>0$? Just to prove that $f$ and $g$ cannot vanish in the same point?

Comment: Since $\frac{df}{dy}=K\,g(y)$, this is equivalent to proving that all the roots of $f$ are simple.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. Yes, you are right.  But it not obvious to me how to prove (1) that f and g cannot vanish in the same point or (2) all the roots of f are simple.